# How to declare typescript module to prevent "implicitly has an 'any' type" error?

Tags: typescript

I'm importing a relative module in my typescript code:

```
import * as NGLViewer from '../../ngl/build/js/ngl.esm'
```

(It's at https://github.com/arose/ngl)
That module is built with typescript and has plenty of types inside it, but for whatever reason it doesn't have a module declaration file. So when I import it, I get this error:

```
52:28 Could not find a declaration file for module '../../ngl/build/js/ngl.esm'.
'/myproject/ngl/build/js/ngl.esm.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

So I thought I could add an ambient module decl in a `modules.d.ts` file:

```
declare module '../../ngl/build/js/ngl.esm'
```

but that gives this error:

```
12:16 Ambient module declaration cannot specify relative module name.
```

I don't want to modify the "ngl" module, and other than that, everything's working fine, so I just want to shut the error up. What's the right incantation in my `modules.d.ts`? Or am I importing it wrong or something?

Answer (score -1):

The error specifies the module declaration can't have a relative module name such as "../../module_name". Have you tried using a package manager such as npm or yarn to add this module to your codebase ?

If you're using a package manager, the proper way to declare the module in your .d.ts file is the following:

```
declare module "ngl"{
    // properties and their types
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- I can't use npm/yarn for this package though. I've read through the "module resolution" section of the doc but I still don't see how to do it.